# Search method using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use search as my retrieve option, this is my simpliest form of searching, what can I do with these codes, No error but not working. Please indicate what is wrong in my code. Give advice, site, solution Thanks.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    ob_start();

//connetion database
    $dbhost = '192.168.0.9';
    $dbuser = 'dsc';
    $dbpass = 'csd';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('ERROR CONNECTING TO MYSQL');

    $dbname = 'dbtips';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $output='';

    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

//query
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnews WHERE udate LIKE '%$searchq%'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($count==0)
        {
            $output = 'There was no search result!';
        }
        else
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                   $udate = $row['udate'];
                   $mis = $row['mis'];
                   $status = $row['status'];



                   $output .= '->'.$udate.'-'.$mis.'-'.$status.'<br>'; 
    }
    }
    }
    ?>      

    //form for searching
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <center>
    <p>
    <input type="text" size="90" name="search" style="text-align:center">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="Search">
    <br>
    <br>
    </p>
    </center>
    </form>
```

Comment: echo " $output .= '->'.$udate.'-'.$mis.'-'.$status.'<br>'"; @Arif_suhail_123 same result sir, thanks

Comment: Just remove the session stuff at the top and the html part from the bottom, hardcode the POST param and run the script on command line and see what you get.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 the button sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to

```
<input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="Search">
```

To this

```
<input type="submit" name="searchbutton" value="Search">
```